# ASP.NET MVC - Razor: Assign a different model to BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

Let's say I have a page showing info about a product. The model looks something like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID {get; set; }
    public string Description {get; set; }
    public bool IsAvailable {get; set; }
}
```

At the top of my page I have `@model MyApp.Models.Product` and everything is working fine.

Now I'd like to add a form at the bottom of my page that lets the user send a mail to ask for further info about the product.

I have a controller with an action `RequestInfo` that sends an email to the site owner, taking this as model:

```
public class InfoRequest
{
    /* ... */
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPhone {get; set; }
    public string Message {get; set; }
    /* ... */
}
```

The problem is, if I create a form using `Html.BeginForm`, every `@Html.TextBoxFor` refers to `Product` model, and I don't know how to specify a different model.

I found on other posts that I could solve by creating a partial view that has `InfoRequest` as model.

Is there a way to solve without using a partial view?

If partial view is the only way, is there a vay to define a partial view *within the page* (ie. not using an external file)?

Thank you!

Comment: I would create a new model that lists both the Product class and the InfoRequest class, then in your views select each item.

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this by using plain html, however, I am not certain that this would work, you might have to edit the name attribute of the input, e.g. `Name="Model.CustomerName"` instead of `Name="CustomerName"`.

```
@Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form" })
{ 
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="CustomerName">Name</label>
   <input class="form-control" name="CustomerName" id="CustomerName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="CustomerPhone">Phone</label>
   <input class="form-control" name="CustomerPhone" id="CustomerPhone">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="Message">Message</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" name="Message" id="Message"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Send</input >
</div>
}
```

Although, the other way of doing it is creating a view model that contains both of the models. 
Step 1. Create a new model that lists both of the classes.

```
public class ProductsInfoVM
{
   public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
   public List<InfoRequest> InfoRequests { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2. Create the view:

```
<table class="table">
 <tr>
   <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].InfoRequest.CustomerName)
   </th>
   <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].Description)
   </th>
   <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].IsAvailable)
   </th>
   <th></th>
 </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{
 <tr>
   <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InfoRequest.CustomerName)
   </td>
   <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
   </td>
   <td>
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsAvailable)
   </td>
   <td>
      @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ProductId }) |
      @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ProductId }) |
      @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ProductId })
   </td>
 </tr>
}
</table>
```

Form:

```
@Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form" })
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.InfoRequests[0].CustomerName, new { @class="control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.InfoRequests[0].CustomerName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.InfoRequests[0].CustomerName, "Your name cannot be blank" ,new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.InfoRequests[0].CustomerPhone, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.InfoRequests[0].CustomerPhone, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.InfoRequests[0].CustomerPhone, "Your phone cannot be blank", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.InfoRequests[0].Message, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.InfoRequests[0].Message, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.InfoRequests[0].Message, "Your message cannot be blank", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Send</input >
    </div>
}
```